# Load google translate word definitions into python

Tags: python, google-translate

**Quick Background**

I am a chemical engineer messing around with python a little. I once took a short introductory course in Java and writes in LaTeX.

**The program**

I am currently working on my first python project and wish to create a program that takes a list of English words from Microsoft's Excel, translates the words into my native language, and gives me a formal definition of the word.

To load the Excel file I used the Pandas plugin (originally XLDR but switched to pandas as it gave me an easier time). Then after a list of strings was created I used Google's translator API to translate the entire list into my native language.

**The problem**

I now wish to add a formal definition of each word to my program. When I go to google translate, i.e. [Translating the word "flourishing"](https://translate.google.dk/#en/da/flourishing), I automatically get a formal definition of the word provided by Google. I figured I could load this definition the same way I did with the translation, but can't find a way how to when looking at the API documentation.

I was hoping someone here could help me get around the problem. I know that Google has some restrictions about crawling their translation service, so there might not be a good way around this for a beginner like me. However, I would love any suggestions as it will help me learn.

**My code**

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd

file_location = "/Users/...List.xls"
xl_workbook = pd.ExcelFile(file_location)
df = xl_workbook.parse("Sheet1")
aList = df['words'].tolist()
[str(i) for i in aList]

translator = Translator()
translations = translator.translate(aList, dest='da')
for translation in translations:
    print(translation.origin, ' -> ', translation.text)
```

Comment: The additional info you are seeing in the web UI are not exposed via the translation API so your next solution would be to scrape the page. There are ways to do such things with python ([beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/?) is the most popular library), however, you might want to first experiment with simple curl/wget calls (to make sure that it's actually possible to scrape the translate page before actually spending time to learn how to make authorized calls with python). I tried this myself but failed.

Comment: More specifically, when running `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" https://translate.google.dk/#en/da/flourishing` (the [gcloud auth ... command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token) is basically a shortcut to print an access token) I get a 403 error. When adding the user agent with `-A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 10575.55.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36"` I actually get a valid html response, but still not the one you're looking for.

Comment: Also, you might want to check google's [terms of service](https://policies.google.com/terms)

Comment: @LefterisS Thanks for the response. Yes, i actually went around and messed with BeautifulSoup but quickly caught 403Errors and looked through terms of services etc. I think you are not allowed to scrape off of google translate. Fortunately, i found a solution using [PyDictionary](https://pypi.org/project/PyDictionary/) which solved the issue easily. I have however encountered a problem in the next part of my program which I have trouble solving, you are welcome to try and answer it if you like.